# How to reduce the React Native apk size

Tags: android, react-native, rollup

I have a react native app (12mg), and should reduce app size to about 5mg in installation state.

I read some reduce size approach ([this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android#split-apks-by-abi-to-reduce-file-size) and [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android#enabling-proguard-to-reduce-the-size-of-the-apk-optional)) and now apk size for ARM is (8mg).

I have 1.8mg assets (mp3,fonts,image & etc) & bundle size is 1.9mg

Is there some approach to reduce more apk size. such as downloading bundle and assets in first start (like games with external data)?

**PS**: I'm not sure but is it possible to bundling with rollup.

Comment: Have you tried compressing your assets?

Comment: @Dan No, svg,ttf and mp3 in my assets